# Changing the spacing of the underline of a UIButton

Tags: swift, xcode

How can I change the spacing between a UIButton and its underline? And also try to make the underline bolder. Any help is appreciated.

My UIButton:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPJwF.png)

The ideal UIButton:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci19k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get such a button, you can split it int 2 elements - the text (not underlined) and a rectangle (as the line).

### SwiftUI

In **SwiftUI** you can achieve your desired design with a Stack within the button with a text and a rectangle in it

```
Button(action: {
    self.anyFancyFunction()
}) {
    VStack(){
        Text("Button")
        Rectangle().frame(height: 5)
    }
    .foregroundColor(.black)
}
```

And it would look like:

[image: Button with bar underneath]

In this example you can adjust the spacing by adding a (positive or negative) offset. You can add a corner radius to the bar and ich you wanted to have it rounded on the edges, you also can use Capsule() instead of Rectangle()

UPDATE:

### UIKit

Regarding UIKit, I think a possible solution could be to create a view with 2 subviews (1. text, 2. bar underneath the text) and then you put a clear button with the same size over it on the same position.

I'll try to add an UIKit example in the afternoon.

Best,
Sebastian

Comment: I am using storyboard, and your solution is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, there is a View called **Rectangle** that is perfectly matched for this. You can add it below any view by embedding them into a simple VStack.
Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       
        Button(action: {
        }) {
            VStack(spacing: 15){
                Text("帖子")
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                Rectangle()
            }
            .frame(width: 70, height: 60, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]